# derivative on closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

A quick question. Why do certain texts insist on taking derivatives on open sets while others explicitly take derivative at boundary points? The most frequent case is in the literature of PDEs when, e.g., one talks about Neumann boundary conditions.

Thanks.